# single row subquery issue

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am using the following query:

```
select P.job_ref, P.emp_num, P.name,
       P.job_title , P.job_type, 
       P.dept_ref, P.dept, J.mgr_rept, 
(select  P.name as manager_name
from PEOPLE P, JOB J
where J.mgr_rept=P.job_ref)
from PEOPLE P, JOB J
where P.job_ref=J.job_ref
```

The issue is the manager and employee names reside in the same table under name. job_ref correlates to mgr_rept in the job table. An employees job_ref would equal a value in the job table that would pull up job information. The manager name however lies in the people table. The mgr_rept value would be the managers job_ref number. Using this query returns more than one row so I'm looking for some help please.

Thank you

Comment: That is confusing. job_ref is the primary key of table job, right? It is not a job type like "buyer", but rather a particular position like "buyer 05 in department A02". A manager also has a job (like "manager of department A02"). So the record for buyer 05 contains a mgr_ref to the record that contains the manager. Each person has a job, so people.job_ref is also not nullable and unique. There is a 1:1 relation between people.job_ref and job.job_ref; you only have two tables to separate job positions from current job holder. Is this right? If not, please tell us primary keys and relations.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should no longer use the old comma-separated join syntax. It has been replaced in standard SQL with explicit joins more than 20 years ago.

Your subquery selects *all* people. It is not linked anyway to the record in the main query. Maybe you confused yourself by using the same table aliases again. It should be about this instead:

```
select 
  P.job_ref, P.emp_num, P.name,
  P.job_title , P.job_type, 
  P.dept_ref, P.dept, J.mgr_rept, 
  (
    select mgr.name 
    from PEOPLE mgr
    where mgr.job_ref = J.mgr_rept
  ) as manager_name
from PEOPLE P
join JOB J on P.job_ref = J.job_ref;
```

I'm not 100% sure however, because I don't understand your table structure completely. This only works if job_ref is unique in table people.